# Problem with displaying/updating drawable resources

Tags: android, resources

I have created a method updateGUI() which include the following method calls:

```
if (settings.isMute()) {
            muteIcon.setIconImage(R.drawable.ic_volume_off_small);
} else {
            muteIcon.setIconImage(R.drawable.ic_volume_small);
}
```

Where setIconImage() is defined the following way:

```
public void setIconImage(int imageFromResources) {
    iconImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), imageFromResources);
    iconWidth = iconImage.getWidth();
    iconHeight = iconImage.getHeight();
    invalidate();

}
```

While running this code the icon image doesn't change as it should. There are both images stored in the res/drawable directory but the ic_volume_off_small does never appear. Does anyone know what could be changed here in order the program works as it should?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are methods of a `View` child you have to override the [`View.onDraw()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) method to tell the system how to draw the image stored in `iconImage` after [`invalidate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) it.

If you are extending [`ImageView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) for `muteIcon` you can directly use or override [`ImageView.setImageResource(resource)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

That is a base class of of MuteIcon? If it something like ImageView, you should call method of super class to actually update image.